# Почему из-за absolute элемента есть прокрутка

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, transform

Почему, когда я задаю transform элементу, появляется полоса прокрутки? Как от этого избавиться, не делая `overflow: hidden`?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

/* 
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

section {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

:root {
  --time: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.super {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container.fluid {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
}

.super__title {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.super__title>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.super__title div {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.super__title span {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}

.question__title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px
}

.question__option {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.question__card__wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}

.question__card {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.question__card__wrapper:nth-child(n+2) .question__card {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.question__card-img {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: transform var(--time);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.question__card-img img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.line {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.line>*:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.question__card-answer {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.question__card-btn {
  background-color: rgba(56, 179, 172, 1);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color var(--time);
}

.question__card__wrapper:hover .question__card-btn {
  background-color: rgba(56, 179, 172, 0.6);
}

.question__card__wrapper:hover .question__card-img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.question__card__wrapper::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  top: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(250, 233, 213, 1);
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform var(--time);
}

.question__card__wrapper:nth-child(n+2)::before {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  right: 0;
}

.question__card__wrapper:hover::before {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<section class="super">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="super__content">
      <div class="super__title">
        <span></span>
        <div>Диагностика волос и кожи головы</div>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <p class="current__question">
        Вопрос <b>1</b> из 6
      </p>
      <p class="question__title">Окрашиваете ли вы волосы?</p>
    </div>
    <!-- .super__content -->
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->

  <div class="container fluid">
    <div class="question__option">

      <div class="question__card__wrapper">
        <div class="question__card">
          <div class="question__card-img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600">
          </div>
          <div class="line">
            <div class="question__card-answer">Да</div>
            <div class="question__card-text">Вы регулярно окрашиваете волосы стойкой, краской тон в тон или делаете мелирование.</div>
            <div class="question__card-btn">Выбрать</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .question__card__wrapper -->

      <div class="question__card__wrapper">
        <div class="question__card">
          <div class="question__card-img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500">
          </div>
          <div class="line">
            <div class="question__card-answer">Нет</div>
            <div class="question__card-text">Вы не красили волосы более года.</div>
            <div class="question__card-btn">Выбрать</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .question__card__wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- .question__option -->
  </div>
  <!-- .container.fluid -->

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в элементе с классом .super отсутствует позиционирование к родительскому элементу.. вам нужно решить вопрос с этим элементом, это на первый взгляд. Но думаю именно тут вся загвоздка.